# Python logging is not creating multiple instance of log files

Tags: python, class, logging, handler

I am trying to create a `class` that can create multiple instances of logging with saved `.log`.

This is my code:

```
import logging
from datetime import datetime
import sys
import os


class DummyLog:
    def __init__(self,
                 log_name: str = datetime.now().strftime('%d_%m_%Y__%H_%M_%S'),
                 logging_level: str = 'debug',
                 string_format: str = '%(asctime)s: %(levelname)s: %(message)s',
                 datetime_format: str = '%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p',
                 log_on_folder: bool = True,
                 log_folder_name: str = 'logs'
                 ):
        self.logName = log_name
        self.logger = None
        self.loggingLevel = logging_level
        self.stringFormat = string_format
        self.datetimeFormat = datetime_format

        if log_on_folder:
            if not os.path.exists(log_folder_name):
                os.mkdir(log_folder_name)
            self.logName = log_folder_name + '/' + self.logName

        self.initiateLogger()

    def initiateLogger(self):
        """ This function will initiate the logger as a single threaded log"""

        self.logger = logging.getLogger(self.logName)
        if self.loggingLevel == 'debug':
            self.loggingLevel = logging.DEBUG
        self.logger.setLevel(self.loggingLevel)
        logFormat = logging.Formatter(self.stringFormat, datefmt=self.datetimeFormat)

        # Creating and adding the console handler
        consoleHandler = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)
        consoleHandler.setFormatter(logFormat)
        self.logger.addHandler(consoleHandler)

        # Creating and adding the file handler
        fileHandler = logging.FileHandler(self.logName + ".log", mode='w')
        fileHandler.setFormatter(logFormat)
        self.logger.addHandler(fileHandler)


dl = DummyLog()
dl.logger.info("hi")

import time
time.sleep(1)

dl1 = DummyLog()
dl1.logger.info("hi")
```

When I run the above code, it creates only one `.log` file and both the `dl` and `dl1` objects are being logged on the same `.log` file.

The console output is printing the `log` 3 times instead of 2 times:

```
01/03/2022 12:01:20 PM: INFO: hi
01/03/2022 12:01:21 PM: INFO: hi
01/03/2022 12:01:21 PM: INFO: hi
```

but I have initiated the `class Dummylog` two times. I am expecting the code change where the `class DummyLog` can be called at multiple instances and each instance will save an individual `.log` file.

I know I am missing something in the `Handler`, but nothing is helping me to come over the required change.

Any help will be appreciated !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your default log name is based on time, but accuracy is second you must put sleep between logger instance or use non-default names:

```python
dl = DummyLog(log_name="name1")
dl.logger.info("hi")

import time
time.sleep(1)

dl1 = DummyLog(log_name="name2")
dl1.logger.info("hi")
```

and the result will be

```
logs
├── name1.log
└── name2.log
```

I found your code main issue, you use a function call in your default argument:

```python
log_name: str = datetime.now().strftime('%d_%m_%Y__%H_%M_%S'),
```

by this `lang_name` initiate with a string at Class definition time and never changed.
You could use solution like this:

```python
import logging
from datetime import datetime
import sys
import os


class DummyLog:
    counter = 0
    def __init__(self,
                 log_name: str = "",
                 logging_level: str = 'debug',
                 string_format: str = '%(asctime)s: %(levelname)s: %(message)s',
                 datetime_format: str = '%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p',
                 log_on_folder: bool = True,
                 log_folder_name: str = 'logs'
                 ):
        if log_name:
            self.logName = log_name
        else:
            self.logName = f"{DummyLog.counter}_{datetime.now().strftime('%d_%m_%Y__%H_%M_%S')}"
        DummyLog.counter += 1
        self.logger = None
        self.loggingLevel = logging_level
        self.stringFormat = string_format
        self.datetimeFormat = datetime_format

        if log_on_folder:
            if not os.path.exists(log_folder_name):
                os.mkdir(log_folder_name)
            self.logName = log_folder_name + '/' + self.logName

        self.initiateLogger()

    def initiateLogger(self):
        """ This function will initiate the logger as a single threaded log"""

        self.logger = logging.getLogger(self.logName)
        if self.loggingLevel == 'debug':
            self.loggingLevel = logging.DEBUG
        self.logger.setLevel(self.loggingLevel)
        logFormat = logging.Formatter(self.stringFormat, datefmt=self.datetimeFormat)

        # Creating and adding the console handler
        consoleHandler = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)
        consoleHandler.setFormatter(logFormat)
        self.logger.addHandler(consoleHandler)

        # Creating and adding the file handler
        fileHandler = logging.FileHandler(self.logName + ".log", mode='w')
        fileHandler.setFormatter(logFormat)
        self.logger.addHandler(fileHandler)


dl = DummyLog()
dl.logger.info("hi dl")

dl1 = DummyLog()
dl1.logger.info("hi dl1")

dl2 = DummyLog()
dl2.logger.info("hi dl2")
```

Answer (score 1):

Do not use [mutable objects as default parameters](http://www.omahapython.org/IdiomaticPython.html#default-parameter-values).  Instead, pass them in runtime or use None as default and set the value.

In your case DateTime is evaluated at function definition time.

**Ex:**

```
def __init__(self,
             log_name = None,
             logging_level: str = 'debug',
             string_format: str = '%(asctime)s: %(levelname)s: %(message)s',
             datetime_format: str = '%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p',
             log_on_folder: bool = True,
             log_folder_name: str = 'logs'
             ):
    if log_name is None:
      self.logName = datetime.now().strftime('%d_%m_%Y__%H_%M_%S')

dl = DummyLog()
dl.logger.info("hi")

import time
time.sleep(1)

dl1 = DummyLog()
dl1.logger.info("hi")
```

OR pass in runtime.

```
dl = DummyLog(log_name=datetime.now().strftime('%d_%m_%Y__%H_%M_%S'))
dl.logger.info("hi")

import time
time.sleep(1)

dl1 = DummyLog(log_name=datetime.now().strftime('%d_%m_%Y__%H_%M_%S'))
dl1.logger.info("hi")
```

Comment: Thats brilliant @Rakesh. This should do the expected one.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @S4eed3sm for the Answer. I am updating the Answer which creates multiple `.log` files and uses `datetime.now().strftime('%d_%m_%Y__%H_%M_%S')` to create a log and have a prefix with it

```
import logging
from datetime import datetime
import sys
import os


class DummyLog:
    def __init__(self,
                 log_name: str = datetime.now().strftime('%d_%m_%Y__%H_%M_%S'),
                 logging_level: str = 'debug',
                 string_format: str = '%(asctime)s: %(levelname)s: %(message)s',
                 datetime_format: str = '%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p',
                 log_on_folder: bool = True,
                 log_folder_name: str = 'logs',
                 log_prefix: str = None
                 ):
        if log_prefix:
            self.logName = log_prefix + log_name
        else:
            self.logName = log_name
        self.logger = None
        self.loggingLevel = logging_level
        self.stringFormat = string_format
        self.datetimeFormat = datetime_format

        if log_on_folder:
            if not os.path.exists(log_folder_name):
                os.mkdir(log_folder_name)
            self.logName = log_folder_name + '/' + self.logName

        self.initiateLogger()

    def initiateLogger(self):
        """ This function will initiate the logger as a single threaded log"""

        self.logger = logging.getLogger(self.logName)
        if self.loggingLevel == 'debug':
            self.loggingLevel = logging.DEBUG
        self.logger.setLevel(self.loggingLevel)
        logFormat = logging.Formatter(self.stringFormat, datefmt=self.datetimeFormat)

        # Creating and adding the console handler
        consoleHandler = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)
        consoleHandler.setFormatter(logFormat)
        self.logger.addHandler(consoleHandler)

        # Creating and adding the file handler
        fileHandler = logging.FileHandler(self.logName + ".log", mode='w')
        fileHandler.setFormatter(logFormat)
        self.logger.addHandler(fileHandler)


dl = DummyLog(log_prefix='one_')
dl.logger.info("hi")

dl1 = DummyLog(log_prefix='two_')
dl1.logger.info("hi")
```

This will create multiple `.log`s with prefixes below

```
logs
├── one_03_01_2022__12_42_02.log
└── two_03_01_2022__12_42_02.log
```